# How to rotate a camera around its own axis in WPF viewport3D?

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, viewport3d

I am working on a 3D application in WPF and having trouble with the camera. It should be possible to rotate the camera around its own axis (with other words, look around) using the mouse but I can not get it to work properly. I create the camera with the following code:

```
PerspectiveCamera perspectiveCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(new Point3D(0, 30, 0), new Vector3D(0, -1, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 90);
perspectiveCamera.NearPlaneDistance = 0.001;
perspectiveCamera.FarPlaneDistance = 1000;

center = new TranslateTransform3D(0, 30, 0);
rot_x = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 0);
rot_y = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 0);
rot_z = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 0);
zoom = new ScaleTransform3D(1, 1, 1);

Transform3DGroup t = new Transform3DGroup();
t.Children.Add(zoom);
t.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(rot_x));            
t.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(rot_y));
t.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(rot_z));
t.Children.Add(center);
perspectiveCamera.Transform = t;
myViewport3D.Camera = perspectiveCamera;
```

And then I try to rotate it using the following code:

```
private void OnViewportMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseLeftIsDown)
    {
        Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
        double rotZAngle = (rot_z.Angle % 360) + oldLeftPosition.X - position.X;
        double rotXAngle = (rot_x.Angle % 360) + position.Y - oldLeftPosition.Y;
        if (rotZAngle < 0) //rotZAngle is negative, make it positive
        {
            rotZAngle = 360 + rotZAngle;
        }
        if (rotXAngle < 0) //rotXAngle is negative, make it positive
        {
            rotXAngle = 360 + rotXAngle;
        }
        rot_z.Angle = rotZAngle;
        rot_x.Angle = rotXAngle;
        oldLeftPosition = position;
    }
}
```

However, it seams that the rotation is not happening around the camera and instead somehere else. The model that I load at position (0,0,0) is becoming visible after I rotate 180 degrees around the z axis which should not be the case.

What am I missing?